# Difference between running code in jupyter notebook and calling the same code in a .py file?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, openai-gym

In a jupyter notebook, I run the following code in a cell:

```
Video(f'./gym-results/openaigym.video.{obj.env.file_infix}s.video000000.mp4',embed=True)
```

where obj is an object whose class is defined in a .py file that I imported earlier.

I also have the same code inside a function in that class:

```
def show_video(self):
    Video(f'./gym-results/openaigym.video.{self.env.file_infix}s.video000000.mp4', embed=True)
```

Which I then call from another cell in the same notebook:

```
obj.show_video()
```

However, for some reason, the first cell embeds a video in the notebook, and the second cell doesn't seem to do anything. **What explains this difference? Clearly code run inside a jupyter notebook doesn't have the same effect as calling the exact same code inside a .py file.**

Comment: I think you are missing `return` in your `show_video()` function.

Comment: Oh right, jupyter notebook basically calls `print` implicitly on an object, or something like that. Well its not `print` because that would show text. What is the command I should use within `show_video()` that would actually ahow the object returned by `Video(...)`?

Comment: I think `return Video(f'./gym-results/openaigym.video.{self.env.file_infix}s.video000000.mp4', embed=True)` should be enough for the video to show. That should embed the video below the line where `obj.show_video` is executed.

Comment: @angardi, yeah it does in fact work, but it wouldn't work if I then called show_video() from somewhere else within the .py file. So I'm wondering if there is a more general command to call from .py so that it behaves as if it was called in a cell in a jupyter notebook.